# mypy does not catch typing error with a subclass of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, class, mypy

I have created a subclass of a pandas dataframe :

```py
class Foo(DataFrame): 
    def __init__(
        self: DataFrame, *args: Dict[Any, Any], **kwargs: Dict[Any, Any]
    ) -> None:
        super(TsFlat, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do other stuffs
```

I have also created a function that uses a `Foo` object as input

```py
def my_function(a: Foo)-> None: 
   pass

my_function(a=pd.DataFrame({"t":[1, 2, 3]})
```

In multiple places in my code, I put a pandas data frame as input of `my_function` and mypy is not catching this mistake.

expected behavior:

`error: Argument "a" to "my_function" has incompatible type "Dataframe"; expected "Foo"  [arg-type]`

**Can someone explain what is going wrong with that?**

It seems to be related to the `DataFrame` class because I have tried to replicate this with another class:

```py
class Employee:                             # base class
    
    def __init__(self,name: str,age: str):            
        
        self.name = name         
        self.age  = age 
        
    def display_name(self) -> None:
        print (self.name)
        
         
class Manager(Employee):            
    pass 

def my_function(Employe: Foo)-> None: 
   pass

donothing(a=Employee("John", "Doe"))
```

and mypy is catching the error as expected.

`error: Argument "a" to "donothing" has incompatible type "Employee"; expected "Manager"  [arg-type]`

Comment: Try adding `reveal_type(pd.DataFrame)` and running `mypy`. You should get `Revealed type is Any`, and this should answer your question. `pandas` is not typed. You're missing [`pandas-stubs`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-stubs/) installed